# Why does Angular repeat filter only have access to its element in the return function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have some Angular code which I have gotten to work but I don't understand why -  being from a C Sharp background and new to JS and Typescript.

```
<tr ng-repeat="colleague in Model.FilteredColleagueListModel | filter:Model.searchText(Model.SearchCriteria)" >

    public searchText(searchCriteria)
    {

        return function (item) {
            if (item.DisplayName.indexOf(searchCriteria) > -1 
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }  

    };
```

And I have a filter but what I don't understand is the nested function. Why is item only available in the return function. Also is the returning function the right way to do it in TypeScript? Is it OK to ask slightly open ended questions like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works very similar to JavaScript ['array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), in fact i wouldn't be surprised if its using it under the hood.

what's happening is your `searchText` method is accepting your search criteria and is called. The method it returns is called by angulars filter on every element in your collection, passing it that element.

If you `console.log(item);` you will see it is not the whole array but each individual item. If your returned method returns true angular will keep that specific item, if it returns false angular will discard it. Exactly like the native filter. So your returned anonymous function is called not once, but for every item in your array.

I can't comment on the syntax and mechanism with regards to TypeScript but returning a method is indeed to correct way to use this functionality, exactly like a native `array.filter()`.

EDIT: Here's the Fiddle i used to make double sure of my comments if interested: http://jsfiddle.net/wf5shz70/

EDIT: @jonas made a very good and important point about statefull filters, i missed that.

Comment: Thanks guys that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are using is a stateful filter (and is discouraged https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> It is strongly discouraged to write filters that are stateful, because the execution of those can't be optimized by Angular, which often leads to performance issues. Many stateful filters can be converted into stateless filters just by exposing the hidden state as a model and turning it into an argument for the filter.

You should consider making the `searchCriteria` an argument to the returned function. Then the syntax would be something like `filter:Model.searchText:Model.SearchCriteria`

```
public searchText()
{

    return function (item, searchCriteria) {
        if (item.DisplayName.indexOf(searchCriteria) > -1 
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }  

};
```